# The simplest Cocoa Binding example

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I am trying to get a basic understanding of Cocoa Bindings and I would like to create a really simple project. I have a class `Person` which has a variable `name` of type `NSString`. Here is how I want things to work:

1. User enters a name into a text field and presses the "Update name" button
2. The string from the text field is saved to an instance of the `Person` class.
3. The label that is bound to the Person Controller (which is bound to the `Person` class) automatically changes its value according to the `name` variable of the `Person` instance.

I've spent hours reading various tutorials and the Apple Mac Developer Library, but each and every example only shows how to get Cocoa Bindings work with tables. When I try to develop something far more simpler I feel that I am completely lost. I have created a base project and the only thing left is to make all the bindings. I am kindly asking to make all the connections for me and hopefully provide me with an explanation. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6hddfxyitqp6uoc/AACgaRhKBhLo6EXCVN9W6GQua?dl=0
The project is a document-based app because I will be developing an app of this type in the future.

Comment: Did you read [Cocoa Bindings Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000167-BBCFBCAG)? Class `Person` must be KVO compliant.

Comment: Bind the value of the label to the controller, Controller Key: `selection`, Model Key Path: `name`. That's all.

Comment: If I just do that I get several exceptions and the app doesn't load. I obviously need to make some connections in my Object Controller. Also, is it possible to implement KVO in a class, i. e. can I make my `Person` class to be KVO compliant? If you can suggest another approach to accomplish the same task I am working on, please do share your knowledge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several reasons why your project doesn't work so lets start again and create the simplest Cocoa Binding Example.

1. Create a new Xcode project, choose Cocoa Application and don't check "Use Storyboards", "Create Document-Based Application" or "Use Core Data".
2. Select MainMenu.xib, select the window and add a Text Field and a Label.
3. Add an Object Controller to the xib. Switch `Prepares Content` on.
4. Bind the Text Field to the Object Controller: bind `Value` to `Object Controller`, Controller Key `selection` and Model Key Path `name`.
5. Bind the Label to the Object Controller: bind `Value` to `Object Controller`, Controller Key `selection` and Model Key Path `name`.
6. Build, Run, Test. Enter some text and hit Return.

The controller automatically creates an instance of `NSMutableDictionary` which is KVO compliant for every key. When the contents of the Text Field is changed, the binding of the Text Field calls `setValue:@"New Contents" forKey:@"name"`. This notifies the binding of the Label and the Label is updated.

Why your project doesn't work:

- In the xib, the content of the Object Controller is connected to the document. The content of the controller should be a Person, not a Document. That's why you get `[<Document 0x618000100750> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.`. Remove this connection.
- Class Person isn't KVO compliant. When the name changes, class Person doesn't emit a change notification and the binding doesn't notice the change. This can be fixed by using a property for `name` instead of an ivar. You don't have to use `setValue:forKey:` to change the name in code, `person.name = [field stringValue]` is ok.
- The content of the Object Controller is set in the `init` method of the document. This is too early, the xib isn't loaded yet and the controller doesn't exist. Set the content in `windowControllerDidLoadNib`. Instead of `addObject` I would use `setContent` but `addObject` should work.

Comment: Your help is much appreciated, this is just an explanation I was looking for. After applying the changes you pointed out, my project became fully working.